# 404 Errors on asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have an asp.net website that continually throws 404 errors.  Here are a couple of examples:

> > > >
> > >       An exception has occurred on the website. Message: The file '/Products/Products/Products/Services/quote/quote/checkout/checkout/Checkout.aspx' does not exist.
> > >       <<<<
> > >       >
> > >       '/Products/Products/Products/Services/Products/quote/Products/Services/quality-assurance.aspx'
> > >       <<<<

We do have a Products folder, but we do not have a '/Products/Products/Products/ folder.

It appears as though something is concatenating real folders from the site together, then putting on an .aspx page from the site.

Any ideas what may be happening?  And, how to fix this problem?

Thanks,
TLF

Comment: who is the caller generating this exception? how are they forming the url? do you have any routing logic? is your normal url access working when you try to access the right path in browser?

Comment: Hello, the links on the website appear to be working just fine. As we browse the website, we do not get errors.  However, we continue to receive e-mails of these type errors from the errorhandler in the Global.asax.  Could this be a problem with web crawlers/robots?  Thanks,